# How to add values to existing array elements?

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I have two arrays **(Arr1 and Arr2)** which I use for `.Countifs Application`.

My third array is fixed size of 7 elements and I want to loop that `.Countifs` through the whole **Array2** and add values to **Array3**.

What I'm doing so far with my code is getting `.Countifs` values to **Array3** and overwriting it each time.

As much as I've tried looking online, all I can find is adding elements to the array but not updating the existing values in the loop.

What am I missing?

```
For y = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)

arr3(y) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets(3).Range("B:B"), arr1(Z, x), Sheets(3).Range("E:E"), arr2(y))

Next y
```

Comment: `arr3(0) = 1` will assign 1 to the 1st element of array 3, then again if you write `arr3(0) = 2` will overwrite the 1st element of Array and store 2 in it.

Comment: Yes, so my arr3 is now all 0s. Then it loops through and stores the values. After looping again I need it to add values to its existing values, and not overwrite them. I hope I can make myself clear.

Comment: You can do `arr3(0) = arr3(0) + 1`

Comment: I've tried using 
arr3(y) = arr3(y) + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets(3).Range("B:B"), arr1(Z, x), Sheets(3).Range("E:E"), arr2(y)) 

which didn't do any good. :(

Comment: It should work, unless your function is not returning any value

Comment: Ahhh it was actually working in the first place! I just failed to see it.
Should I delete my question or mark yours as an answer now?

Comment: Mark the Answer :). It can be helpful for people with same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
For y = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)


Debug.Print arr3(y)
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets(3).Range("B:B"), arr1(Z, x), Sheets(3).Range("E:E"), arr2(y))

arr3(y) = arr3(y) + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets(3).Range("B:B"), arr1(Z, x), Sheets(3).Range("E:E"), arr2(y))

Next y
```

Run the Code using F8 and you will know what values are being calculated in Array and function, Debug will print them in Immediate Window **(Cntrl + G)**

Comment: This works, thank you. This loop is inside another loop which redims my arr3 everytime before this loop. Rediming the array adds an element to the end of my arr3, do you know how could I stop this from happening?

Comment: Remove that Redim Line

Comment: But I need my arr3 to be all 0s before this loop starts again.

Comment: If you want them to be 0, then why was this a Question, you don't need to add it's previous value, because it will be zero!!

Comment: Edit your question and Explain exactly what you are trying to do and where you are failing in that.

Comment: I have answered what you asked in Question. If there is something else you can ask a new question now. @JurasSulcas

Comment: `Redim arr3(Number Here)` is the dimension you want to keep constant, if you dont want to add another element. And nobody can answer that without looking at code.